# Can I get value from attribute table when I click on it for using in my plugin?

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqt

I created a plugin which helps us to calculate the azimuth(bearing) between points. Here is the user interface;

[image]

When I click the points, it must fill the blanks automatically. Of course this point data has own coordinate information (X and Y). However, I cannot achieve that. Please help me!

I am using Python 3.6 - Qgis 2.99 and PyQt5